# Is it possible to create a Python class that inherits from a complex class, but calculates the values based on extra parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to create a custom Class that inherits from a complex class, but I'm not able to achieve what I want. Here's a code example:

```
class MyComplex(complex):
    def __init__(self, real, imag, imag2):
        super().__init__(real, imag + imag2)

# Create an instance of MyComplex with custom initialization parameters
my_complex = MyComplex(3.0, 4.0, 5.0)

# You can now use my_complex just like a regular complex number
print(my_complex)  # Output: (3+4j)
print(my_complex.real)  # Output: 3.0
print(my_complex.imag)  # Output: 4.0
```

But this returns a `TypeError: complex() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

And if I try to use the `__new__()` function then I can create the inherited class, but it's not possible to use more arguments to initialize the values nor update them in the `__init__()` function because it returns a `AttributeError: readonly attribute`.

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't understand what the third argument is for...

Comment: You might want to check out the video by *mCoding*: *[`__new__` vs `__init__` in Python`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zsV0_QrfTw)*.

Comment: @nokla it's just a simplified example, in reality the second argument will be calculated using multiple arguments with multiple operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, but bear in mind that `complex` is an immutable object so you can't inherit like you do with mutable (user-defined) classes. Instead, this is achieved via the dunderscore operator `new`:

```
class MyComplex(complex):                                                                               
    def __new__(self, real, imag, imag2):                                                               
        return super(MyComplex, self).__new__(self, real, imag+imag2)
```

Note that so defined your first print statement returns `(3+9j)`.

`new` vs `init`: https://builtin.com/data-science/new-python

You should also note that you need to overload operators in order for them to return the correct type. For instance

```
print(MyComplex(1.0, 2.0, 3.0) + MyComplex(2.0, 3.0, 4.0))
```

will print `(3+12j)`, an object of type `complex`, not `MyComplex`, as you may hope at first.

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks like this fixes the issue and also helps me decide that inheriting from complex object is a no-go for my project since I need mutable values after creation and instantiation. Thumbs up for you!